# SQL INNER JOIN multiple tables error

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `orderregel` 
INNER JOIN `klant` ON order.KlantId = klant.KlantId 
INNER JOIN `product` ON orderregel.ProductId = product.ProductId 
INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = order.OrderId;
```

> ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order.*, orderregel.*, product.*, klant.* FROM `orderregel` INNER JOIN `klant` O' at line 1

My database: order(OrderId, KlantId(FK)), orderregel(OrderregelId, OrderId(FK), ProductId(FK), KlantId(FK)), klant(KlantId, Naam, Voornaam), product(ProductId, Naam)

I want to display product.Naam, klant.Naam from each orderregel who has an own order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
INNER JOIN `klant` ON order.KlantId = klant.KlantId
```

you also need to tick the MySQL reserved word `order`

```
INNER JOIN `klant` ON `order`.KlantId = klant.KlantId
```

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Notice where the error starts and tells you:

> right syntax to use near 'order

Same thing for:

```
INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = order.OrderId;
```

to

```
INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = `order`.OrderId;
```

Rewrite:

```
SELECT * FROM `orderregel` 
INNER JOIN `klant` ON `order`.KlantId = klant.KlantId 
INNER JOIN `product` ON orderregel.ProductId = product.ProductId 
INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = `order`.OrderId;
```

Edit: as per OP's comment but with ticks around the MySQL `order` reserved word.

```
SELECT * FROM orderregel 
INNER JOIN klant ON orderregel.KlantId = klant.KlantId 
INNER JOIN product ON orderregel.ProductId = product.ProductId 
INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = `order`.OrderId;
```

Comment: Edited SQL: 
SELECT * FROM `orderregel` 
 INNER JOIN `klant` ON `order`.KlantId = klant.KlantId 
 INNER JOIN `product` ON orderregel.ProductId =   product.ProductId 
 INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = `order`.OrderId; 

ERROR: #1054 - Unknown column 'order.KlantId' in 'on clause' 

But im sure that i typ the right column name -.-'

Comment: Fixed, Thanks! 

Final SQL: SELECT * FROM `orderregel` 
INNER JOIN `klant` ON `orderregel`.KlantId = klant.KlantId 
INNER JOIN `product` ON orderregel.ProductId = product.ProductId 
INNER JOIN `order` ON orderregel.OrderId = `order`.OrderId;

Comment: @Selimhan40 that's great, glad to hear it. *Cheers* just the wrong names for the `order` table.

Answer (score 0):

Quick reordering of the inner join statements may help (not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM `orderregel` 
INNER JOIN `klant` ON orderregel.KlantId = klant.KlantId 
INNER JOIN `product` ON orderregel.ProductId = product.ProductId 
INNER JOIN `order` ON order.OrderId = order.OrderId;
```